# Dataframe with Array Column to New Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, feather

Actually i have an `feather` file that im loading to an Dataframe.

And this Dataframe have a column with `languages`  in each row. Like the abone one:

| student_id | name | created_at | languages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo | 2019-01-03 14:30:32.146000+00:00 | [{'language_id': 1, 'name': 'English', 'optin_... |
| 2 | Bar | 2019-01-03 14:30:32.146000+00:00 | [{'language_id': 1, 'name': 'English', 'optin_... |

My question is: How can i generate an new Dataframe only with `student_id` column and the rest of `languages` array?

For example the above one:

| student_id | language_id | language_name | optin_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | English | 2019-01-03T14:30:32.148Z |
| 2 | 1 | English | 2021-05-30T00:33:02.915Z |
| 2 | 2 | Portuguese | 2022-03-07T07:42:07.082Z |

// EDIT:

Exported Dataframe as JSON (`orient='records'`) for testing purposes:

```
[{"student_id":"1","name":"Foo","created_at":"2019-01-03T14:30:32.146Z","languages":[{"language_id":1,"name":"English","optin_at":"2019-01-03T14:30:32.148Z"}]},{"student_id":"2","name":"Bar","created_at":"2019-01-03T14:30:32.146Z","languages":[{"language_id":1,"name":"English","optin_at":"2021-05-30T00:33:02.915Z"},{"language_id":2,"name":"Portuguese","optin_at":"2022-03-07T07:42:07.082Z"}]}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), then convert to columns with [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
out = (df
  .explode('languages', ignore_index=True)
  .pipe(lambda d: d.join(pd.json_normalize(d.pop('languages'))
                           .rename(columns={'name': 'language_name'})
                        ))
)
```

Output:

```
  student_id name                created_at  language_id language_name                  optin_at
0          1  Foo  2019-01-03T14:30:32.146Z            1       English  2019-01-03T14:30:32.148Z
1          2  Bar  2019-01-03T14:30:32.146Z            1       English  2021-05-30T00:33:02.915Z
2          2  Bar  2019-01-03T14:30:32.146Z            2    Portuguese  2022-03-07T07:42:07.082Z
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @mozway. That `pipe` funcion returns me `ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['name'], dtype='object')`

Comment: this is weird. the same overlapping error again, even with `ignore_index=True`

Comment: Can you provide a DataFrame constructor of your input for me to test?

Comment: of course. i added as edit in the post

Comment: @Hudson I see, there was already a `name` column, see update ;)

Comment: you're the best!! things works perfectly nice! Thanks for helping me ;)